# Access to single dataset

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Give access to a single dataset.

User have access to all datasets through "inheritance". Dont know how to remove this. I just want the user to have access to a single dataset.

Any ideas of how to do this? Anybody can guide me through the process?

Comment: please clarify - by 'single dataset' do you mean 'single table within given dataset'?

Comment: Several tables within a dataset. The user have access to all datasets now but we want to limit the access to a single dataset. All tables within the dataset should be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 levels from which users get access to the Big Query datasets. The IAM & Admin level and the dataset level.

The permissions a user has in the IAM & Admin level will apply to all datasets (inherited). For example if a user has the "Project Editor" role, the "BigQuery Data Editor" role etc., then they will be able to access all datasets.

So you would have to [revoke access in the IAM & Admin level](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#revoking-console) for that user  and then go to the specific dataset and [give them access in the dataset level](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#controlling_access_to_a_dataset).